# Converting StreamListener with headers to Functional Model

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Because `@EnableBinding` and `@StreamListener` are deprecated, I need to migrate existing code to the new model, however I could not find any information on whether the argument mapping available in Spring Cloud Stream is still supported and/or any clean workarounds.

My original method:

```
@StreamListener("mysource)
public void processMessage(byte[] rawMessage, @Header(required = false, value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) byte[] rawKey) {
    processMessage(rawMessage, rawKey);
}
```

I managed to convert this to work as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "mysource")
public Consumer<Message<?>> mySource() {
    return message -> {
    byte[] rawMessage = message.getPayload().toString().getBytes();
    byte[] rawKey = (byte[]) message.getHeaders().get("kafka_receivedMessageKey");
        processMessage(rawMessage, rawKey);
    };
}
```

However, what I would prefer is one that maximizes framework support with respect to argument mapping and/or automatic type conversions.
I attempted:

```
@Bean(name = "mysource")
public BiConsumer<Message<byte[]>, MessageHeaders> mySource() {
    return (message, headers) -> {
        byte[] rawMessage = message.getPayload();
        byte[] rawKey = (byte[]) headers.get("kafka_receivedMessageKey");
        processMessage(rawMessage, rawKey);
    };
}
```

But this gives an error at startup: `FunctionConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet - The function definition 'mysource' is not valid. The referenced function bean or one of its components does not exist`

I'm also aware that along with `Supplier` and `Consumer`, `Function` is also available, but I'm not sure how to use a Function in this case instead of a `BiConsumer` or if it's possible, so looking for examples on how to do this type of migration seamlessly and elegantly with respecting to consuming and producing messages plus headers from/to Kafka.

Comment: First, BiConsumer is not a supported type of function. But I also don't understand your argument. The first argument in your consumer is `Message` and the second is part of the same `Message` (headers). What value would you expect out of it? You are doing `message.getPayload()` already, so you can just do `message.getHeaders()` as well, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's mainly for backward compatibility (more or less); i.e. the ability to leverage the existing converters from my first example. Ideally I want only two parameters: byte[] payload and byte[] header (a single header specified via the @Header annotation). I like/prefer the flexibility and affordances of the previous framework. But I guess that's going away too?

Comment: So, I agree, perhaps my BiConsumer should have been BiConsumer<byte[], byte[]> with specifying annotations somehow. But I see how this could get awkward.

Comment: The problem with annotation is that they actually get in the way and introduce potentially another point of failure. On top of that they couple your function to a specific framework while function itself is completely "faceless" and could easily be reused without any changes in different context (e.g., REST endpoint, AWS Lambda, stream etc). That said, we are considering introducing some type of wrappers to bring back functionality you are describing, but for the record I am not a fan ;)